# Prove that the common chord passes through the origin.

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

> Consider the parabola $x^2=4ay$. Two focal chords are constructed, and
>   the interval that the chord makes with the parabola are diameters of
>   two circles.
>
> Prove that that the common chord of the two circles passes through the
>   origin (vertex of the parabola).

I am having trouble finding a purely geometric way of proving this result.

[image]

Comment: That's a neat theorem.

Comment: I have a coordinate proof of the following: Given a circle whose diameter is a focal chord of the parabola, the line tangent to the parabola at its vertex ($V$) meets the circle at $P$ & $Q$ such that $|\overline{PV}| |\overline{QV}| = -3a^2$ (using "signed" distances). That is, the [power of $V$ with respect to the circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) is $-3a^2$, a value that depends only upon the parabola itself. Thus, given any two such circles, $V$ has the same power with respect to each, so that it must lie on their *radical axis*, ie, their extended common chord.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a parabola with focus $F$ and vertex $V$; define $a := |\overline{VF}|$. Let $\overline{PQ}$ be a focal chord of the parabola, with $M$ its midpoint. Let $F^\prime$, $P^\prime$, $Q^\prime$, $M^\prime$ be the projections of the corresponding points onto the directrix. (Note that $|\overline{VF^\prime}| = a$.)

[image]

It is "known" that the tangents (not shown) at the endpoints of a focal chord are perpendicular, and that they meet at the point on the directrix halfway between their own projections. In our scenario, that point must be $M^\prime$, so that the circle with diameter $\overline{PQ}$ is tangent to the directrix at $M$. Let $r := |\overline{MM^\prime}|$ be the radius of that circle.

It is also "known" that the tangents at $P$ and $Q$ bisect respective angles $\angle FPP^\prime$ and $\angle FQQ^\prime$. This implies that $F$ is the common reflection of $P$ over $\overline{PM^\prime}$ and $Q$ over $\overline{QM^\prime}$, so that $\overline{FM^\prime}\perp\overline{PQ}$. Define $m := |\overline{FM^\prime}|$. A little angle chasing shows that $\angle FM^\prime F^\prime \cong \angle FMM^\prime$, so that the similar right triangles yield
$$\frac{2a}{m} = \frac{m}{r} \qquad\to\qquad m^2 = 2 a r \tag{1}$$

This comes in handy for calculating the [power of $V$ with respect to the circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point):

$$\begin{align}
\text{power of $V$ wrt $\bigcirc{M}$} &:= n^2 - r^2 \\
&\,= n^2 - (r - a)^2 - 2 a r+ a^2 \\
&\,= |\overline{M^\prime F^\prime}|^2 - 2 a r + a^2 \\
&\,= m^2 - (2a)^2 - 2 a r + a^2 \\
&\,= (m^2 - 2 a r) - 3 a^2 \\
&\,= - 3 a^2 \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

We observe that this value is independent of our choice of $P$ and $Q$, and is therefore a constant of this configuration. Consequently, for any two focal-chord-diameter circles, vertex $V$ has the same power with respect to each; this places $V$ on the circles' [radical axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis), which for intersecting circles is the line containing their common chord. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

Woah!! Amazing Problem!
[image]

Let the chords be $AC$ and $BD$. It is well known that the tangents from a focal chord intersect on the directrix and that the two tangents are perpendicular. If we drop the perpendicular $AA'$ from $A$ to the directrix, then $\angle A'AE = \angle AEF = \angle ECA$ so the circle with diameter $AC$ passes through E and is tangent to the directrix at $E$. Thus the power of $F$ with respect to $(AEC)$ is $EF^2$. Similarly, the power of $F$ with respect to $(BGD)$ is $GF^2$. Let $F'$ be the reflection of $F$ with respect to the origin. Then the power of $F'$ with respect to $(AEC)$ is $EF'^2$ and similarly the power of $F'$ with respect to $(BGD)$ is $GF'^2$.

Now by Linearity of Power of Point, we have that $$\text{Pow}_O(AEC) - \text{Pow}_O(BGD) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \text{Pow}_F(AEC) - \text{Pow}_F(BGD) \right) + \frac{1}{2} \left( \text{Pow}_{F'}(AEC) - \text{Pow}_{F'}(BGD)  \right)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} ( -FE^2 + FG^2 + EF'^2 - GF'^2 )$$
$$ = 0 $$ because $FF' \perp EG$

And we are DONE!!!

(Note that power of a point is a directed quantity and hence the powers of $F$ are taken with a negative sign)