# Focal Chords of a Conic

Tags: conic-sections

Let $F$ be the focus of a conic, and let $P_1 Q_1$ and $P_2 Q_2$ be two focal chords of the conic, passing through $F$.  Circles are drawn with $P_1 Q_1$ and $P_2 Q_2$ as diameters.  Prove that the radical axis of these circles passes through a fixed point.

Note: This is a generalization of the result in this link: [Prove that the common chord passes through the origin.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609884/prove-that-the-common-chord-passes-through-the-origin)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof for the case of an ellipse. An analogous reasoning should work for a hyperbola. (See the link given in the question for the case of a parabola).

The supposed fixed point $M$ must be, by symmetry, the intersection of all radical axes with the line $FF'$ through the foci of the ellipse. We can consider, for instance, the circles having as diameter the major axis $AB$ and the latus rectum $DE$ of the ellipse (see figure below) with their radical axis $LK$ intersecting $FF'$ at $M$. From:
$$
LM^2=FL^2-FM^2=CL^2-(CF+FM)^2
$$
one finds:
$$
FM=a(1-e^2){e\over2},
$$
where $a$ is the length $CA$ of the semi-major axis,
$e=CF/CA$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse
and we used the result $FD=a(1-e^2)$ for the semi-latus rectum of an ellipse.

[image]

We want to show that point $M$ has the same power with respect to any circle having a focal chord through $F$ as diameter, thus proving that it lies on all radical axes.

Let's take then a generic focal chord $PQ$, with $FP\le FQ$ (see figure below). If $\theta$ is the acute angle formed by $FP$ with the major axis, then by the cosine law (applied to triangles $FPF'$ and $FQF'$) we have:
$$
FP={a(1-e^2)\over1+e\cos\theta},
\quad
FQ={a(1-e^2)\over1-e\cos\theta}.
$$
If $O$ is the midpoint of $PQ$, the power of point $M$ with respect to the circle of diameter $PQ$ is $OM^2-OP^2$. We have:
$$
OP={FP+FQ\over2}={a(1-e^2)\over1-e^2\cos^2\theta}
$$
and
$$
OF=OP-FP=a(1-e^2){e\cos\theta\over1-e^2\cos^2\theta}.
$$
We can then compute $OM$ with the cosine law:
$$
OM^2=OF^2+FM^2+2\,OF\cdot FM\cos\theta=
\\
=a^2(1-e^2)^2\left(
{e^2\cos^2\theta\over(1-e^2\cos^2\theta)^2}+
{e^2\over4}+
{e^2\cos^2\theta\over1-e^2\cos^2\theta}
\right)
$$
and finally obtain:
$$
OM^2-OP^2=a^2(1-e^2)^2\left({e^2\over4}-1\right).
$$
As the power of $M$ doesn't depend on $\theta$, then $M$ lies on the radical axis of any pair of circles having a focal chord as diameter.

[image]